# Accessing Controller Through AJAX

Tags: java, ajax, spring

I want to access my controller through ajax but I'm new to this.
Basically Whenever a request fired through jsp it is handled bt the specific controller and controller after doing its job it's return a value(Basically **ViewName**) which will will redirect to the next page.
So the same thing I want to use through ajax.

JSP Page
-------------

```
<a href="#" onclick=myFunction(150,200)>ADD</a>
```

JS
-----------

```
function myFunction(x,y){
    var num1= x;
    var num2= y;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: operation.htm,
        data: {"add1=":num1,"add2=":num2},
        success: function(response){
            //what i will do with the viewname here? how to display the page
        },
        error: function(e){
            alert("Error"+e)
        }
    });
}
```

So the data first will be vallidate by the controller if the **values are > 500** then i t must return the return page else the same page i want to be returned

Controller
--------------------

```
@RequestMapping(value="/operation.htm")
public class Controller{

  @RequestMapping(params="add1")
  public String showResult(@RequestParam Map<String,String> params){
     int x= params.get("add1");
     int y= params.get("add2");

     if(x>=500 && y>=500){
        model.addAttribute("result" x+y);
        return "result";
     }else{
        return "samePage";
     }
}
}
```

How to made ajax to call this controller and when my controller will return the viewname of the next page **What ajax will do with it?**

Comment: Remove the `=` signs: `data: {"add1":temp,"add2":featured},`

Comment: Why would you think the browser receives the view name? Spring handles the view name. Perhaps you need to read up on how Spring MVC works.

Comment: ya i aware about that may i have interpreted wrong but i was having no idea If i'm calling my controller through ajax then after executing controller the command again have  to come back to ajax. One thing eating my brain when controller returns the viewname it will be handle by viewresolver and redirect to the another page or it comes to ajax through ajax we have to render the page like below examples as shown by users

Comment: @lucumt ya checking

Comment: The point in using Ajax is to get rid of expensive page redirection. Return the result, not the view name, and display the result in the existing view.